# Настройка комментариев в PhpStorm

Tags: html, phpstorm, webstorm

Собственно вопрос вот такой: работаю с IDE давно, и раньше в HTML разметке при написании того или иного тега (или начала блока) автоматически прописывался комментарий с его окончанием.

К примеру так: `---END HEADER-->`

Не могу вспомнить как вернуть эти комментарии. Помогите кто знает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать с помошью `|c` филтрами

[док тут](http://docs.emmet.io/filters/#comment-tags-c)

Попробуйте сделать так

Добавьте комментарии для тагов.

```
div>div#page>p.title+p|c
```

Это будет открыватся как ...

```
<div>
    <div id="page">
        <p class="title"></p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page -->
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я это в emmet знаю, хотелось бы автоматически настроить в шторме

Comment: в нете было сказано что `emmet` работает и на `phpStorm`.

Comment: конечно работает, это основной инструмент коддинга